# Google Sheets Conditional Format Custom Formula -Sum of 3 cells > cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I have tried to use the following custom formula to see if the sum of H+I+J is greater than F. On each row, if this is the case the row would highlight.

I am getting odd results. That appear to be not correct.

=SUM($H2 + $I2 + $J2) > $F2

Comment: Where did you ApplyTo?

Comment: I tried same formula and indeed seemed strange results. Then I changed formula to `=if(SUM($H2 + $I2 + $J2) > $F2),1,0)` and it worked perfectly. Then I changed back to your formula and it still worked perfect! That's either finger problems or some strange anomaly with Google Sheets. If still not right for you, then post a link to a sheet showing the off behaviour.

Comment: I applied it to F1:J999; Also I am not able to get your IF function to work it shows invalid.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this changing the formula: 
=SUM($H:H + $I:I + $J:J) > $F:F

Thanks